# Total number of 4 digit numbers in which the digits are in descending order

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The question, as stated in the title, is:

> Find the total number of 4 digit numbers in which the digits are in descending order.

Answer given: $\displaystyle {10 \choose 4} \text{ or } 210.$

---

I've tried listing doing the possibilities of these numbers:

- Numbers starting with $9$:
  $9876,9875,...,9871,9870; 9765,9764,...9761,9760; 9654,9653,...,9651,9650;9543,9542,9541;9432,9431,9430,9420;9321,9320,... \text{and so on.}$

I could go on and count all the numbers in this way, but it's quite tedious and not very optimal. How do I use combinatorics here?

I would prefer a complete explanation.

**EDIT**: All the digits have to be different, as pointed out by @TonyK. I appologize for not clarifying earlier.

Comment: $0$ is a digit too! You don't explicitly disallow it, but it doesn't occur in your list.

Comment: @TonyK yep I missed it, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Are leading zeroes allowed ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: If the digits have to be in descending order, the first one can't be $0$ (assuming the digits all have to be different). ExtremeRaider, you don't say whether the digits all have to be different! I think this might explain the disagreement with 715 vs 210.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I would say no because putting a zero in the beginning would make the number a 3 digit-number.

Comment: Aren't you going to edit in those $0$'s, Extreme? And perhaps clue us in on whether repeat digits are allowed? If it's a complete explanation you're after, it might help to give us a complete question!

Comment: @TonyK yes I noticed that I forgot to specify that all the digits should be different, but how can I consider a 4 digit number such as 4444 to be in descending order? I thought it was obvious that numbers with one or more repeating digits should not be counted, but I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: Why on earth don't you just edit your list instead of inserting that woebegone comment?

Comment: @ExtremeRaider: this is why I am asking. From the given answer, it seems that they are allowed.

Comment: @TonyK I don't think it matters whether I include them in the list or not, it's not a very efficient way to begin with.

Comment: @ExtremeRaider: about your comment to TonyK: you are wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust could you please provide an solution? I'm very confused about how to solve it.

Comment: @ExtremeRaider: sorry, I can't answer an inaccurate question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I apologize for making it inaccurate, please let me know what edits I should make to the post to make the question more accurate.

Comment: Didn't you read the comments ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've edited the question, is it better now? Are there any more changes that I need to make? Again, I apologize for not clarifying before.

Comment: You can select four different digits out of $10$ digits in $\binom{10}4$ ways. Given such a selection of $4$ distinct digits, there is only one way to order the digits in descending order. Thus, each selection corresponds to a unique $4$ digit number that satisfies our condition

Comment: @ShubhamJohri thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help!

Comment: You still haven't addressed the issue of leading zeroes correctly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I have not added that because 4 digit-numbers with leading zeroes would not be considered 4-digits numbers, they would be 3-digit numbers. The question clearly states 4-digit numbers.

Comment: In fact, having distinct digits rules out $0000$, which would otherwise be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has already been given, but I feel for explaining the theory behind the answer.

The solution is to find the amount of distinct subsets of the set of numbers from 0 to 9. Having these subsets, we can "reorder" the order in which the numbers appear (the order in sets the elements appear is not important). Therefore, computing the result is done by finding the number of unordered 4-combinations.

$$\frac{n!}{r! · (n - r)!} = \frac{10!}{4!(10 - 4)!} = 210$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Such a number is completely determined once you choose *which four digits* appear in it.

Answer (score 1):

1. How many four-digit numbers are there in which all the digits are different?
2. Given four different digits, how many four-digit numbers can we make using them?
3. Divide your answer to 1 by your answer to 2.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that:

1) When you select a group of digits, there is only one way to arrange them in descending order.

2) Using any digit more than once in a sequence will violate the descending property.

3) To ensure descending order, $0$ may appear only as the least significant digit or none at all.

*i. Sequences with $0$:* There are ${9 \choose 3}$ of them, all ending with $0$.

*ii. Sequences without $0$:* There are ${9 \choose 4}$ of them.

[Pascal's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule) gives us ${9 \choose 3} +  {9 \choose 4} = {10 \choose 4} = 210$